# How to make a ruby method like Array() or Integer()?

Tags: ruby

I have a class `Schema`, and I would love to be able to have a method `Schema()` or something like that.

Is this possible, and if so, how is it done?

Comment: Did you try it? It's not a very good idea, though.

Comment: My confusion was because I thought that it was related to the class, not just some global method that began with a capital letter. I see that it's bad practice, but good to know that the obvious answer was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply define it in the top namespace, completely independent of your `Schema` class.

```
def Schema(options)
  ...
end
```

And then call it. If it's a method with no params, you will still always have to call it as `Schema()`.

Comment: Nope, you would define it just like that. Try it!

Comment: Oh, ok.  yeah I see that they can.  Confusing though - makes 'em look like constants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's good to know, but it's also good to know that this is considered bad practice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as mentioned below, however it contradicts ruby name convention, which states:

> Method names should start with a lowercase letter, and may be followed
>   by digits, underscores, and letters